# Android - Contact name as link which is embedded with a phone number

Tags: android, textview, android-contacts

I am working on an text view in Android. This text view should hold the contacts as a link. Could you please help me in accomplishing this.

Say, I have a contact whose name is Matthew and his mobile number is +876543321
I also have another contact whose name is Jackie and his mobile number is +987823787
and the final contact whose name is JetLi and his mobile number is +8978786762

I need a text view which displays the data in the below format

Matthew ---> JetLi --->Jackie

Here by clicking on either Matthew or JetLi or Jackie, the end user can place a call to these respective folks as the name is linked to the mobile number

Could any of you please let me know how to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Comment: I have made a Relative layout (Orientation horizontal) with 3 textviews. It came up like this

Comment: I have made a Relative layout (Orientation horizontal) with 3 textviews. It came up like this  Matthew(876543321) -->  JetLi(987823787) -->Jackie(8978786762). Again this is a text and readonly.  Need to implement android:clickable="true" and android:onClick="clickHandler" for each of the textviews. But is there a good/eloquent way to hide the contact numbers and display the name alone. please let me know. Thanks a lot Prmths.